Hot water pipes expansion hits frame
I have a newly built double story house. When I open hot water on wash basin in main toilet on level1, i can observe water dripping kind of sound. Plumber and builder has mentioned it is due to hot water pipe expansion when hot water flows through it, pipe hits the frame. After a few minutes this tick tick sound goes away when pipe becomes hot.
My observation is that this noise is coming from the floor. Most likely hot water coming from ground level is hitting steel frame due to pipe expansion.
Since the noise can be heared only 3-4 times and after that we have to wait till pipes get cold, so plumbers can’t locate exact point. Warranty manager and plumbers are not very helpful in identifying and i’m kind of frustrated b/c i hear this sound in evenings during quit times.
If anyone has similar issue in past plz share your experience.
Much appreciated

The pipes should be installed with something to prevent them from rubbing directly on the framing, particularly if the framing is steel and the pipes are copper (I guess you didn't say what the pipes are made of.) If they are copper and the frame is steel, contact can lead to galvanic corrosion and leaks.
Normally these days that's some sort of low-friction plastic. In former times a strip of lead was common. A dense/hard felt also works.
